# Register Master Account - incorrect token

Tags: php, slim, userfrosting

I am getting the following error trying to register [UserFrosting's](http://www.userfrosting.com) master account:

> Sorry, that configuration token is not correct.

The only thing I managed to capture is

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)
```

I did see some discussions on this topic, but so far no mention of any solutions.

Comment: So, I'm guessing you found the configuration token in your `configuration` table, and copied that into the registration field, but it's not working?

Comment: @alexw Yes, I found the token. It was my first attempt installing UserFrosting on AWS where www and db servers were separated. I messed something up with aws configuration and ended up with a token mismatch. Started fresh, set up www and db connections properly and everything went ok. Thanks.